# C-read a line from a file starting with a character

Tags: c

(I'm a bit new at programming in C so go easy on me) I'm trying to make a text adventure-like game where it reads in the tile information from a text file. I am trying to define the different tiles in the file in this sort of format:

1. (current position)EC:1
2. (Position if traveled North)EC:4
3. (Position if traveled South)EC:3
4. (Position if traveled East)EC:0(they can't go this way)
5. (position if traveled West)EC:5
6. (current position description)EC:"You see a red ball."

And repeating that for each of the positions. I am wondering how I can get my program to read the file and read in information starting at the current position of that tile. For example The player just traveled to position 1, so get the description, print it, and make and available directions available. How can I read in that specific information starting at a specified current position?

Comment: An introductory book on C would be a good place to start.

Comment: Use fseek by storing last offset value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you read the line succesfully to `myLine`.

Use [strchr](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strchr.htm), read the value after the character '**:**' .

Here is an example:

```
const char myLine[] = ""; 

//Read Line Here!!!

const char getAfter= ':';

char *direction = strchr(myLine, getAfter);

if (direction != NULL)
{
    direction++; 

    printf("Direction is %s\n", direction);
}
else {
    printf("Nothing to Read");
}
```